# Why my ecs auto scaling action is not working?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, autoscaling

I created REPLICA service and added 2 policies for scaling it. One for scale-in, second is for scale-out. Configured alarms for them and started testing service.

When CPUUtilization value pass the alarm limits and alarm's state becomes ALARM. It's history says 'Successfully executed action...'. In service i see  that `desired count` value becomes 2, but only one task is running.
What the problem? How should i configure scaling to run additional tasks?

Service load balancer [image]

Alarm config
[image]

Scaling policies

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to screenshots, It seems your scaling policies are working fine. However, Your RUNNING tasks do not equal the number of the desired count.

I suggest you check the 'Events Tab' to see the exact reason why your tasks were not able to run.